# One word for a curious child

Tags: meaning, nouns, vocabulary

What would you call (in a single word) a child that asks a lot of questions, leading you to admire that fact?

(In Russian, for example, there is such a word. Is there in English?)

Comment: One word will never be enough for a curious child.

Comment: I think you've used the word in your title - *curious*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adjective 'inquisitive' may be what you're looking for. It is defined: 'having or showing an interest in learning things', a synonym being 'curious'. As a person who shows an interest in learning, questions (which admire people like you) are likely to be second nature to them.

It also means 'unduly curious about the affairs of others; prying' (May be seen as a negative).

From the above, you could call the child 'inquisitive', or 'posiquisitive' to make it, the **noun**, aptly positive.

Comment: I don't think there is a way of expressing in a single word that you admire the quality. You would have to say something like _intelligent and curious_.

Comment: I think "curious" gives a more positive connotation than "inquisitive", especially for a child. You could always just use "admirably curious".